# Moment.js keeps returning UTC instead of Local Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm having what I hope/assume is a simple and silly issue getting Moment.js to return the local date.

I'm passing in this date/time string: **2015-02-19T06:32:00.001-05:00**

Using this code:

```
var departureDateTime = "2015-02-19T06:32:00.001-05:00";
moment(departureDateTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); // returns 2015-02-19
```

That looks correct.  However, if I inspect the time with the code below it will return the time in UTC, which will cause the date to be incorrect (a day in the future) at certain times during the day.

```
moment(departureDateTime).format("h:mma")); // 11:32am
```

What am I missing? I thought the default for Moment.js was to return the local time, so I'm confused as to why it wouldn't return 6:32am instead of 11:32am.

Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: I have tried your code on a recent `moment.js` version and it shows me 1:32pm, which is accurate since I'm in UTC+02:00. Are you using this in the browser or Node.js? Which version of moment.js are you using?

Comment: Good point Dan, I was just about to edit the post.  I'm running this in Parse CloudCode and it occured to me that its local time is UTC so local() or utc() are the same thing.  So what I need to figure out is how to get back to the original date/time.  Running 1.7.2.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to get the date in the timezone originally encoded in the string.

Comment: @Dan what about [`parseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) ? _"Moment normally interprets input times as local times (or UTC times if moment.utc() is used). However, often the input string itself contains time zone information. #parseZone parses the time and then sets the zone according to the input string."_

Comment: I've added my solution. The Moment.js documentation is a bit obtuse on that regard. `parseZone` also seems to work, and at this point I am thoroughly confused by the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do it:

```
var dateStr = "2015-02-19T06:32:00.001-05:00";
moment(dateStr).utcOffset(dateStr).format("h:mma")
```

(From here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/)

**Edit:** The intended way to do it, according to the documentation identified by K_C, is to use [`parseZone`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/):

```
var dateStr = "2015-02-19T06:32:00.001-05:00";
moment.parseZone(dateStr).format('h:mma');
```

Comment: Perfect!!  Both options that you point out actually do work as intended, but I'll follow the parseZone code as laid out above.  Thank you, Dan, I really appreciate it!